# How to count unaccented English letters in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, unicode

I'm trying to count the number of characters that are unaccented English letters in a string. For example, I would want the count to be 1 for the string "né!".

I thought I would be able to check if each character is in the range 'a'-'z' or 'A'-'Z', but that would include `'é'`:

```
'é' >= 'a' && 'e' <= 'z';
true
```

Both accented and unaccented letters seem to have the same code point:

```
"eé".codePointAt(0);
101
"eé".codePointAt(1);
101
```

I tried using regular expressions, but the string `"né!"` was treated like the 4-character string `"ne'!"`:

```
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var c = str.charAt(i);
        if (re.test(c)) {
            console.log("Is a letter: " + c);
            numLetters++;
        } else {
           console.log("Is not a letter: " + c);
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Is a letter: n
Is a letter: e
Is not a letter: ́
Is not a letter: !
```

How can I find the number of characters that are unaccented English letters?

Comment: [`"né!".normalize("NFC")`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`String#normalize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) to get the composed form of a string.

```js
let str = "né!";
let letters = str.normalize().match(/[a-z]/ig);
console.log(letters?.length ?? 0);
console.log(letters);
```

Comment: @EllenSpertus I wasn't the one to downvote, but the downvote is probably because the answer is incomplete. See what happens with that code if you use `let str = "Неће бити";` instead of your example string. I'd say that the answerer's username checks out :-).

Comment: @IgorLevicki The code here is just to serve as an example. The question also does not mention the need to support letters outside of a-z and A-Z.

Comment: @Unmitigated The question was how to count unaccented English letters, but if the input string is coming from outside (i.e. untrusted input such as user or another system), then it makes sense to consider the implications of someone passing non-Latin characters. You can't count on novice developers not to copy your example code verbatim. In one of our corporate projects I once found code copied from CodeProject which had a bug in it. Someone pointed it out 50 comments below, but the developer who copied it didn't read the comments. That's why you should include error checking in your example.

Comment: @IgorLevicki I've updated the answer with optional chaining now.

Comment: @Unmitigated Thanks, but if I am not mistaken Ellen also wanted `A-Z`, no?

Comment: @IgorLevicki That's handled by the ignore case (i) flag.

Comment: @Unmitigated You are right, I missed that. Time for bed it seems :-)

Comment: @Unmitigated Still, rewording the question might help it be more easily found and Latin is certainly more general than English.